# How would I show that $2^n - 1$ is a solution to the recurrence relation:

Tags: recurrence-relations

$a_n$ = 2$a_{n-1}$ + 1, with the initial conditions $a_0$ = 0, $a_1$ = 1

Apparently the solution is from the Tower of Hanoi problem, but having trouble coming with the this on my own.

Comment: You can prove it by induction.  Suppose that $a_n=2a_{n-1}+1$ for all $n$ and that $a_k=2^k-1$ for some $k$.  Then $a_{k+1}=2a_k+1$ by the recurrence relation and then $2a_k+1=\dots$ by the induction hypothesis which simplifies to... which by the principle of mathematical induction implies...

Comment: Hint: write it as $\;a_n+1=2(a_{n-1}+1)\,$. P.S. `with the initial conditions` That's a first order recurrence, so it only needs *one* initial condition.

Comment: It is very easy just go straight....

Comment: @Community Not sure I see how this is a duplicate, since the referenced question had asked `how to solve` while this one was only asking `how to prove` that a certain form is in fact a solution. The answers may overlap, of course, but that alone doesn't make the question a duplicate.